# Shorter type hints for long types

Tags: python, type-hinting, typechecking, python-typing

(Excuse the bad title, maybe someone can suggest a better one)

Just getting into typehinting/typechecking and wanted to add on for a function to which I'm passing a selenium webdriver object which shows:

```py
In:  type(driver)
Out: selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver.WebDriver
```

Is there a way it can be made shorter without typing the whole thing? (no pun intended)

I found about about aliases and wanted to know if it is safe to use something like:

```py
WebDriver = selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver.WebDriver
WebElement = selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement

# Function definition follows:
def get_object(driver: WebDriver, ....) -> WebElement:
    ...
```

Two questions remain:

- Do I need to manually create the aliases or is there an easier way to do it?
- Notice the alias name and the last part of the type is kept the same for easy identification. Safe or no?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The pythononic-way to do this is changing the imports line:

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver import WebDriver
from selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement import WebElement

# Function definition follows:
def get_object(driver: WebDriver, ....) -> WebElement:
```

Comment: When you say changing the imports line, you mean we need to add another `from selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver import WebDriver` right? we already have a `from selenium import webdriver`

Comment: basically: you want to create an import line that imports the smallest symbol you wish to reuse later in the code.  You can have multiple import lines from the same package even, importing different symbols from different depths if you need to.